# AppleScript not looping all numbers when using repeat

Tags: loops, applescript, repeat

I am using this script to close all "Alerts" in my notification bar:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
        set numwins to (count windows)
        repeat with i from numwins to 1 by -1
            click button "Close" of window i
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

However this doesn't close them all, even when there are no "Alert without Close button".

`try catch` didn't help. What's wrong?

Comment: The code works on my machine. Maybe you are using Mojave and your Script Runner doesn't have permission to send Apple Events.

Comment: In fact I’m on Catalina, but as it can close some notifications, I don’t think it’s permission issue. It seems to be some indexes being not looped but I am already closing notifications from the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your script and it seemed to run correctly on my machine, but there is always a potential for problems when you use a repeat loop on a mutating list: in other words, a list that changes as the repeat loop progresses. Each time you close a window Notification Center changes its window list and updates the properties of the remaining windows; the script can simply lose track. I'm a little surprised it doesn't throw errors when this happens, but...

You can try this code and see if it works. rather than referring to windows by index it repeatedly tries to close the last window, ignoring any errors, and keeps on until the window count is zero or it loops 100 times (that last is to prevent an endless loop in case something goes wrong).

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
        repeat 100 times
            try
                tell last window
                    click button "Close"
                end tell
            end try
            if (count of its windows) = 0 then
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

**EDIT**

Per comments, the above doesn't work quite as advertised, so let's switch it over to AppleScriptObjC:

```
use framework "Foundation"
property NSUserNotificationCenter : class "NSUserNotificationCenter"

NSUserNotificationCenter's defaultUserNotificationCenter's removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

This seems to do the trick on my machine. Of course, `NSUserNotificationCenter` is deprecated as of 10.14, so this won't work forever — eventually you'll have to shift over to the notification's framework — but it should work for a few more OS versions.

**EDIT 2**

Per another comment, anyone working on os 10.14 or later (Mojave and Catalina, to date) can do an equivalent AppleScriptObjC routine using the UserNotifications framework, like so:

```
use framework "UserNotifications"

set notificationCenter to class "UNUserNotificationCenter"'s currentNotificationCenter
notificationCenter's removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

Note that I've used a slightly different syntax (merely calling `class "UNUserNotificationCenter"` rather than setting up a property). Both work; the `property` syntax is only preferable when you need to pass the class to handlers.

Comment: *It doesn’t throw errors* because the list is processed backwards. Another way to capture the list is `repeat with aWindow in (get windows)`. The `get` keyword won’t invalidate the objects, too.

Comment: My machine starts to have problems when there are 4+ alerts. For the mutating issue, that’s part of the reasons why I am processing backwards... For your code, if there is 1 window that doesn’t have “Close”, it won’t close other notifications... Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Maybe I’m on Catalina so AppleScriptObjC is quite deprecated — NSNotificationCenter is not found. I end up just repeatedly run my originally loop for 3 times. Marking this as accepted as answer can be helpful for others.

Comment: It's hard to tell with pre-release software like Catalina; no telling what bugs they are still ironing out. But I can work up a version using the notifications framework that is supposed to replace NSNotification center.  Give me a bit on that.